# sql server 2014 install after visual studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, installation

I have Visual Studio 2015 installed on my Windows10 already and I now want to install SQL Server 2014. But I remember that you had to have SQL Server before Visual Studio.

As I already seem to have SQL Server and SQL Server Compact Edition under my program folders.

Will I run into trouble now if I attempt to install the proper SQL Server? IS there a way to uninstall them or would I need to do a complete install of Visual Studio to install SQL Server first?

Or the best case scenario, that the SQL Server installation won't create any issues, besides the windows firewall exception and .net 3.5 which i have already checked is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it didn't seem to matter, could install and run sql server even after having Visual Studio installed first :)